# Is there a type of Database Server that don't support parameterized query (or prepared statement) by their most recent version?

Tags: database, prepared-statement, parameterized

I am writing a report about parameterized query (or prepared statement) technique. And I must write in it if all Database now by their most recent version support this technique or no. I know mysql, sql server and oracle support this. What about others?

Answer (score 0):

Others that support prepared statements: PostgreSQL, DB2, Sybase, HSQL, H2, Apache Derby